# Backup Script with Lock giving Invalid Syntax Error

Tags: linux, shell, scripting

I'm setting up a simple backup script to backup key files on my server every 12 hours. Just trying to test the script now and I'm getting the following error message;

```
 python /<pathwayhere>/autobackup.sh
 File "/<pathwayhere>/autobackup.sh", line 2
 exec {lock_fd}>/<pathwayhere>/backuplock || exit 1
              ^ SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I have ensured all of the encodings are correct, and I've recreated the file both in the terminal and using WinSCP as well to no avail. I can't work out why the script won't run, so any advice and ideas would be appreciated.

Here is the original file;

```
#!/bin/bash
exec {lock_fd}>/<pathway here>/lock/backuplock || exit 1
flock -n "$lock_fd" || { echo "ERROR: flock() failed." >&2; exit 1; }
if [ -z "$STY" ]; then exec screen -dm -S backup /bin/bash "$0"; fi

python /<pathway here>/scripts/backup/workwarn5.py
sleep 5m
python /<pathway here>/scripts/backup/workwarn1.py
sleep 1m
python /<pathway here>/scripts/backup/workstart.py
```

To note as well, my python scripts work fine. It is just a simple shell script I am trying to run.

Comment: That error message looks like it's from Python, and you also seem to be running `python /<pathwayhere>/autobackup.sh`. Shouldn't you run the script with a shell, as in `bash /path/to/autobackup.sh` (or just `/path/to/autobackup.sh` if the execute permission bit is set)?

Comment: You were totally correct. I was running the command incorrectly.

However, I've now got this error message instead;

    #!/bin/bash: No such file or directory
    ERROR: flock() failed.

Any ideas?

Comment: you should [edit] your question to show exactly what commands you run, and what the exact error message is